# viewpager with drag drop disable

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using a viewpager generated ontouch of a button, contains a drag drop fragment.So while I drag drop items swipe disturbs the drag drop and screen hangs some times, I tried to disable swipe for the particular fragment , but was unsuccesfull, what I tried is

As My view pager is using PageAdapter class, so on onPageChangeListener's `onPageScrolledChanged(int state)`

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) { 
    switch (state) { 
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING: mPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
            break;
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE: mPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
            break; 
    }
}
```

I also tried 
`viewpager.seEnabled(false);` on `pageSelected()`,
but nothing works, as my class is extending `RelativeLayout` 
so I cannot extend `Viewpager` to use `onInterceptTouchEvent()`,

kindly guide messed up, thanx

in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to disable the viewpager scrolling then:

```
    mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                return true;
        }
    });
```

And when you want to re-eanble it then:

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(null);
```